# MySql incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql, datetime, mariadb

I know this question has probably been asked but I cant for the life of me figure out what is wrong with my datetime value that mysql doesnt seem to like.

In my situation, I am appending 'explain ' in front of every query to see what the explain plan looks like. This is done BEFORE the actual query is run. The problem is mysql doesnt like the date format in the explain but the regular query runs fine.

This is the error I recieve:

```
SQL Error: 1292, SQLState: 22007 
Incorrect datetime value: '11/19/2015 19:49:34.076' for column    'createdTime' at row 1
```

Query is:

```
explain delete from LoggableActivity where createdTime<'11/19/2015 19:49:34.076'
```

What is wrong with this format? it looks good to me...
And why only the query appended with explain isn't working?

Some more info:
I am using an entity manager in java to create and execute the queries and the date being generated is a result of Java's 'new Date(milliseconds)'.

Thanks

Comment: ask it from http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @payamsbr thanks, I will ask there.

Comment: If necessary, you can use `STR_TO_DATE()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MONTH/DAY/YEAR is not (repeat *not*) the best sequence in the world

YEAR/MONTH/DAY is much better

try this:

```
explain 
select from LoggableActivity 
where createdTime<'2015-11-19 19:49:34.076'
```

---

Consider this article at wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Look at how many people in the world use either a "big endian" (yyyy-mm-dd) or "little endian" (dd-mm-yyyy) date format. It is far wiser to treat date strings as "big endian". In particular starting a date string by year reduces possible confusion with dates where the day number is less than 13.

Comment: While this may be the best way to go, it doesn't seem to solve my issue. As I mentioned, the regular query (same datetime and all) is going through OK. It complains once I append explain to the query. My guess is it has something to do with the string conversion and execution of the query.

Comment: I don't know the internals of either MySQL or Java, but the explain prefix to your query must pass the query through a filter of some sort, and that alteration affects the way the date is being handled. Perhaps it's a bug - I cannot say. But if you want rock solid queries then stop using mm/dd/yyyy in any code (not just sql). Most native java I'm familiar with uses iso standard date sequence. Please do take note that mm/dd/yyyy is just a tiny portion of the worlds population hence standards like ISO 8601

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was in fact  exactly what you mentioned. There was a bug in the algorithm used to create the explain query string. Fixing the date to yyyy/mm/dd resolved the issue. :)